# How do you use short-term AWS credentials with django-storages?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to migrate away from using long-term access keys to further harden my security.

I am seeking to implement short term security credentials for the AWS services I am using, such as S3. Specifically, I have an IAM user which can assume a role which gives it access to S3. This role is only assumed for a limited amount of time before it expires  and then needs to be reassumed. I am wondering if anyone has successfully implemented this pattern using django-storages, and if they can provide advice?

It seems like there is support for a config called `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` 
[here](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/70fa8d96665f0c5e44aacd6c782f6489fa8dc11e/storages/backends/s3.py#L372) but there is no documentation for it.

Additionally, there is a config called `AWS_S3_SESSION_PROFILE`, but I can't tell if this is related to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is this running on EC2?

Comment: @jarmod This is running outside on a server outside of AWS (not EC2).

Comment: Suspect that django-storages supports AWS profiles (configured in ~/.aws/config) and because AWS profiles support [credentials from IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html), you may be able to set it up easily. Set AWS_S3_SESSION_PROFILE to the name of the profile you add to ~/.aws/config (marketingadmin in the example) and you'll need an initial profile representing the IAM User (user1 in the example) that has permission to assume the role.